# Unable to start Google App Engine instance

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I couldn't get my new version deployed or started (after stopping it) properly on GAE:

[image]

All I get is:

[image]

It was working fine before until I tried to deploy yesterday. I tried deploying to a new version

```
gcloud app deploy
```

also tried deploying to the same vesion

```
gcloud app deploy --version 20200418t204444
```

also tried deploying without promoting it

```
gcloud app deploy --no-promote
```

but none of them managed to get it starting.

This is the `app.yaml` if it helps:

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
service: default
resources:
  memory_gb: 4.0
  disk_size_gb: 10
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  APIHOST: 'http://10.148.0.5:31837'
```

My region is `asia-south1`

I looked at the compute engines, **quotas**, logs, and there are no errors or limits exceed. I thought it was a Google server/zone issue, so I tried again today and it still fails.

I have run out of clues and ideas. Does anyone know anything about this? I'm happy to provide more information.

This is the activity log of the app engine:

[image: ng]

I'm using a managed VM, I went into the Google Compute Engine > Zones, and it shows that `asia-south1` has no instances, but `asia-southeast1` has two. Could this be the cause?

[image]

If this was it, how can I change the app engine zone? (and why did it changed by itself?)

---

> **UPDATE**

I found these logs under "GCE Instance Group", is it related?

[image]

Comment: Did u check the logs?

Comment: @skaul05 Yeah I checked and there is no error logs on the app engine, but I found many `NOT_FOUND` errors on `compute engine` `removeInstance` activity, do you know what it means?

Comment: I tried to replicate this, I didn't found any problems. I understand that your app has been deployed with no errors, but you see internal error when you try to open it in browser. I such case you can check the exact error in the browser console. What kind of app is it, is it something I am able to replicate from some tutorial?

Comment: @vitooh nothing on the browser console, this is the server not starting. It's a SSR NodeJs React app. It was working all this time until yesterday it suddenly fails, and I can't start it anymore nor deploy a new version that works.

Comment: It seems that this is a matter of resource capacity in asia-south1 region. Sometimes a region which is experiencing a high demand of resources can be temporary unavailable for new deployments to balance the workload. I tried to create App Engine today in asia-south1 and it seems it's not possible. `gcloud app create` is just showing this region.

Comment: @vitooh last time I could wait for another day and deploy and it will be fine. However, this time it stopped my existing version suddenly, and I can't deploy until now (Not all my apps, but just the default one so far) I'm running out of clues, so now working on moving to GKE instead.

Comment: I think there is other option as well, you can try to use Cloud Run where you can use Docker containers as well https://cloud.google.com/run

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is my first time in stack overflow, I've been pass that error with using this command `gcloud app logs read` follow everything there if you find error, maybe nanoid my suggest using nano@3.0.0 so install that, and the other you can browse your own there is a lot explanation there.